# Partial mock of Ok() gives me "Value cannot be null". (Parameter 'result')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

In an ASP.NET Core Web Application API template project, if I create a partial mock and return a OK(someObject) I always get an error saying 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'result')'

The funny thing is that this works fine when I run the application (F5).

What doesn't work is the unit test that uses Moq. Then I get this error.

I'm using:
.NET Core 3.0 (I also get this error when using 2.1).
The latest Moq 4.13.1
The latest xunit 2.4.0

Controllers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyTest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : BaseAccessController
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WeatherForecast>> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                int userId = 3;

                if (HasAccess(userId) == false)
                    return Forbid();

                var rng = new Random();
                return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray()); // This is where the error happens!
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyTest.Controllers
{
    public class BaseAccessController : Controller
    {
        protected virtual bool HasAccess(int userId)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Moq;
using Moq.Protected;
using MyTest;
using MyTest.Controllers;
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        interface IBaseAccessControllerProtectedMembers
        {
            bool HasAccess(int userId);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void MyUnitTest()
        {
            // Arrange

            var mockController = new Mock<WeatherForecastController>();

            mockController.Protected()
                .As<IBaseAccessControllerProtectedMembers>()
                .Setup(x => x.HasAccess(3))
                .Returns(true);

            // Act
            var result = await mockController.Object.Get(); 

            // Assert
            var actionResult = Assert.IsType<ActionResult<WeatherForecast>>(result);
            var returnValue = Assert.IsType<WeatherForecast>(actionResult.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

First, the action is defined to return

```
public async Task<ActionResult<WeatherForecast>> Get()
```

Yet nothing is *awaited* and it also tries to return a collection of `WeatherForecast`

```
return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
{
    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
})
.ToArray());
```

Secondly if using `ActionResult<T>` there is no need to manually do `Ok(..)` result. Just return the intended object.

#### Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types)

So I would first advise refactoring that action to follow suggested syntax from documentation

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<WeatherForecast[]>> Get() { //Note the array
    try {
        int userId = 3;

        if (HasAccess(userId) == false)
            return Forbid();

        var rng = new Random();
        WeatherForecast[] results = await Task.Run(() => Enumerable
            .Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray()
        );
        return results;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The test should also follow proper async syntax and assert the expected return type

```
[Fact]
public async Task MyUnitTest() {
    // Arrange
    var mockController = new Mock<WeatherForecastController>() {
        CallBase = true; //so that it can call `HasAccess` without issue
    };

    // Act
    ActionResult<WeatherForecast[]> actionResult = await mockController.Object.Get(); 

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
    var returnValue = Assert.IsType<WeatherForecast>(actionResult.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to change the mockController to this:

```
var mockController = new Mock<PersonsController>(mockPersonsService.Object) { CallBase = true };
```

Works fine now. Thanks!! :-)